# Scrolling on mobile

Tags: html, mobile

can anyone assist, why these article pages do not properly scroll on **mobile**? They don't seem to scroll at all or it is very hard to go down.

Example URL: www.palapp.co.uk/blog/a-couple-things-to-do.html

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can scroll the page in my phone, maybe it's the device in what you are testing.

Comment: No, tested on various devices. It doesn't scroll "freely" like on the homepage (www.palapp.co.uk). Anything perhaps preventing it on the HTML or CSS?

Comment: Tested in three phones and work on the three,¿ are you testing in virtual devices or real devices ?

Comment: Hi, testing it on real devices (iPhones).